# .NET Core: Nunit 3 test adapter runs other tests in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nunit-3.0

Using VS2015 community update 3 on Windows 7, with last NUnit3. I can only "Run All" tests, other options (Ctrl+R,Ctrl+T or Run Selected tests) in most cases execute unrelated tests, even from other class. 
I also noticed that test name in tooltip in TestExplorer may be not equals to test name in hovered item in list.

project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": { 

    "NUnit": "3.4.1",
    "NUnitLite": "3.4.1",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-alpha-2"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
  },

  "testRunner": "nunit",

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  }
}
```